# Jersey + Gradle with maven dependencies not working

Tags: maven, jersey, gradle, dependency-management

Hi I am following the jersey sun documentation. I have deployed before this simple pom.xml before

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

and Add the repository

```
  <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
```

Nevertheless when I try to do this with gradle, it does not seem to be working, is not downloading the rest of dependencies that requires and aparently I have to explicitly put  javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1 and even jersey-core. This is my build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

List compileLibraries =['com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.14',
                        'com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly2:1.14',
                        'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.14',
                        'javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1']


dependencies {
    compile (compileLibraries )

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

httpPort = 8888
stopPort = 9451
stopKey = 'foo'
```

**Is this proper gradle behaviour? How can I do as same as with maven?**

**Edit**

Just for the sake of this and if somebody is interesting in seeing a gradle build file that work with gradle you can go to

https://github.com/necronet/XTradeJerseyimpl/

Thanks!!

Comment: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/simple_gradle_java_jersey_web_service_dependency_issue

Comment: The given repository does not make sense neither in Maven or in Gradle, cause you are accessing a SNAPSHOT repository but you are using releases in your dependencies.

Comment: I've also try it with https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/ The only reason why I use the snapshot repo with no luck.

Comment: Matt I saw that post that's why I am double checking If I have to explicitly all the dependencies although when using maven I do not need to add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that the dependency from jersey-server to jersey-core isn't being properly interpreted by Gradle. Looking at [the pom](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.14/jersey-server-1.14.pom) shows that the jersey-core dependency is in a profile, which is likely why it's not being picked up. And jersey-core has the dependency on jsr311. Sounds like Gradle should probably account for the profile marked 'activeByDefault' in cases like these.

That said, you've already hit upon the solution, which is to specify the two jars directly - and it's still less lines to configure than the maven xml :)

Also, it looks like all the jars you need can be found in mavenCentral, so the snapshot repository isn't contributing anything.

This doesn't solve the need to explicitly mention those two extra jars, but I hope this explains why, and you might want to raise an issue on [Gradle Jira](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE) if you think this should be addressed.

Comment: I just ran into this as well - did anyone follow up on Gradle Jira? It sounds like it's uncommon enough to encounter these "profile dependencies," but still irritating.

Comment: I did some digging and found that it should be resolved - http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1997